# Google Earth showing only a black screen on Samsung GT-S7582L, how to solve?

Tags: samsung, google-earth, samsung-galaxy-s-duos-2

When I install Google Earth from Google Play, initially it works, you can see the 3D Earth centered in the screen. Then the first time tips appears, teaching you how to use the fingers to zoom, change angle, etc.

When you close the last tip, no more 3D Earth, only a black screen. The interface seems to work, you can see the pictures of places at the bottom of the screen, and you can go to in app settings.

Maybe my device isn't enough for Earth.

Comment: Yeah. Remove that las one too and we are done. This question looks ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to downgrade to version 7.x of Google Earth.

To downgrade, for example, download apk from here: http://google-earth.en.uptodown.com/android/download/52238

You will have to enable installation from unknown sources: http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/forum/enable-unknown-sources-android-install-apps-outside-play-store-0150603/

Then disable auto updates for Google Earth: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/21/psa-as-of-play-store-v4-3-10-you-can-finally-disable-automatic-updates-for-certain-apps-and-update-all-will-honor-these-settings/

Periodically try to go back to newest version and check if the BUG, if it is a BUG at all, resolved.