# Google Earth opens to a black screen after latest update

Tags: google-earth

Google earth want black screen 2 updates ago, is there a fix for this yet? I have tried twice to reload and it still comes up black screen. I have also tried reverting to an older version, that worked until a new update made it go black screen.

Device is Samsung Galaxy Tab 4

Comment: Similar to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/87141/google-earth-showing-only-a-black-screen-on-samsung-gt-s7582l-how-to-solve

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in a Samsung Galaxy Duos 2 may work for your tablet too. It look like the same problem.

The solution is to downgrade to version 7.x of Google Earth.

To downgrade, for example, download apk from here: http://google-earth.en.uptodown.com/android/download/52238

You will have to enable installation from unknown sources: http://gs4.wonderhowto.com/forum/enable-unknown-sources-android-install-apps-outside-play-store-0150603/

Then disable auto updates for Google Earth: http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/08/21/psa-as-of-play-store-v4-3-10-you-can-finally-disable-automatic-updates-for-certain-apps-and-update-all-will-honor-these-settings/

Periodically try to go back to newest version and check if the BUG, if it is a BUG at all, resolved.